# How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the pair of equations $x_1+x_2+…+x_6=20$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the pair of equations 
\begin{align}x_1+x_2+\dots +x_6&=20  \\ x_1+x_2+x_3&=7\end{align}

How do you find  non-negative integer solutions?

Comment: The second factor in your answer should be based on the number of solutions of $x_4+x_5+x_6=13$.

Comment: my bad. Is it correct now?

Comment: I think it's ok now.

Comment: so is it always arranged where the first number is what the equation equals and then you add one less then the number of terms?

Comment: Saying 'always' is a dangerous thing in math.  Subtle differences in wording can change answers quite a bit.  But in your case you can use a 'stars and bars' argument.  See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @Lil  Think of each '*' as repesting a value of 1, and each '|' as a separator.  So counting the partitions of 7 into 3 nonnegative integers is equivalent to counting all distinct permutations of the string "*******||".  There are $\binom{7+3-1}{2}$ ways to place the separators.

Comment: @NovaDenizen  
similarly if I had x4+x5=9 it would be (10!/1!9!)?

Comment: Yep. That's how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. You can also think of it in terms of permutations.

The number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$ is the number of permutations of a multiset with seven $1$'s, and two $+$'s. This is $$\frac{9!}{7!\ 2!}.$$
Similarly, the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_4+x_5+x_6=13$ is the number of permutations of thirteen $1$'s, and two $+$'s. This is $$\frac{15!}{13!\ 2!}.$$

This is why the first number in your combination is what the variables equal, and the second is "one less" the amount of variables, since you're permuting the $+$'s.

Comment: similarly if I had x4+x5=9 it would be (10!/1!9!)?

Comment: Yup. Nine $1$'s and one $+$ are $10$ things in total. You have to $\textbf{choose}$ one spot out of ten for the $+$, which is just $C(10,1)$. Of course this also $C(10,9)$. So yes you are correct!